# Angular - simple controller understanding

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement a simple controller to output navigation items:

in index.html I have the following:

```
   <nav ng-controller="Nav">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="c in catalog">
                {{c.name}}
                <p>{{c.url}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

and in controllers.js I have:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

angular.module('c.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', [function() {

  }])
  .controller('MyCtrl2', [function() {

  }])
    .controller('Nav', function Nav($scope) {
        $scope.catalog = [
            {'name': 'Nav 1',
                'url': '#/view1'},
            {'name': 'Nav 2',
                'url': '#/view2'},
            {'name': 'Nav 3',
                'url': '#/view3'}
        ];
    });
```

It doesnt work though, the repeat dosnt work and i just get the following output:

```
    <nav  ng-controller="Nav">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="c in catalog">
                {{c.name}}
                <p>{{c.url}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Have have I done wrong, or havent done at all?

EDIT:

I have the following on my html tag:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

I can see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument
```

Comment: What is your error message in console?

Comment: Do you have n-app with the name of the module?

Comment: I have edited my question with more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included ng-app somewhere (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp)?

For instance:

```
 <html ng-app='c.controllers'>
```

Often when the double curlys {{ }} show up it's because Angular hasn't seen an ng-app yet.

Edit:
Here's an example of setting up a module and controller together (from http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02)

```
 var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

 phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function PhoneListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
    'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
    'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
   'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'}
   ];
 });
```

Comment: I added it to the html tag. Does the controller name have to match the app name?  I thought you have different controllers under the same app?

Comment: The module names need to match.  The name to focus on is "c.controllers" in your case:   angular.module('c.controllers', [])  Make sure that name matches your ng-app

Comment: And yes, you do want different controller names.  You look good there, it's just the module name that's the issue.

Comment: I took this project skeleton from github: angular-seed. All i have done is add that controller

Comment: Ahh.  That controllers.js can be confusing.  Focus on app.js for the moment (https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/js/app.js)  That's the closer parallel to what you're trying to do right now

Comment: In that seed, controller.js is being injected into app.js  You'd need to have an app.js equivalent to inject into.  But you can also just have an app.js that declares the controllers directly in it.

Comment: Check out http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02  for an example of declaring a controller in the same file as the module declaration.

Comment: so just a simple function sitting in app.js would be enough and act as a controller?

Comment: ok that works byt just placing the function in app.js.  Seems a bit odd just sitting in there though

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have named the module name incorrectly

```
<html ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

Would need a module called App with a controller inside called AppCtrl

```
angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
        console.log('AppCtrl', this);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

To this

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="c.controllers">
```

But in my opinion change the name of your current module to something better